# Configuring headers on ListView without GridColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to figure out how I can create a `ListView` in XAML that has headers that are evenly spaced apart **without** using `GridViewColumn`. The reason I don't want to use `GridViewColumn` is because the headers only stretch to the total width of the content, and trying to get them to stretch to the entire available width of their container isn't as easy as it sounds (at least I haven't found a clean way to do it).

So far I have come up with something like this in XAML (written in sort of pseudode for brevity):

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefintion/>
          <RowDefintion/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid">...</Grid>
     <ListView>
</Grid>
```

Where the first nested Grid `HeaderGrid` would contain all of my headers and the `ListView` would hold each element in the List. My issue is how to align the columns of the `HeaderGrid` with the columns of the `ListView` without using something like `SharedSpaceScope`. The reason for that is that `SharedSpaceScope` does not allow you to use star sizing, and therefore we wind up back where we started where the column headers just shrink to fit the content instead of taking up all available space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you actual problem is How to define proportional Column in a `ListView`, i am going to adresse that.

Defining the `ListView` columns by yourself instead of using the `GridView` Columns will redirect you to the same problem you were facing initially, so i suggest you stick with the `GridView`,

Let say you have the following Model:

```
 public class Sample
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Location { set; get; }
}

  private ObservableCollection<Sample> _items=new ObservableCollection<Sample>()
    {
        new Sample()
        {
            Location = "Loc1",
            Name = "Nam1"
        }
    }; 

    public ObservableCollection<Sample> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }

        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

then you Xaml should look something like this

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  x:Name="Lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>           
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

to divide the `ListView` width amoung all the columns you could either:

**First**

Define a Converter that will do that by using the `ActualWidth` of the `ListView`:

```
  public class ColumnDeviderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return int.Parse(value.ToString()) / 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and update the Xaml:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <YourNameSpace:ColumnDeviderConverter x:Key="ColumnDeviderConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  x:Name="Lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" Width="{Binding ElementName=Lv,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource ColumnDeviderConverter}}"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="{Binding ElementName=Lv,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource ColumnDeviderConverter}}"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>           
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**Second**

Use one of the several already implemented classes and behaviors, one of them is [ListView-Layout-Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25058/ListView-Layout-Manager), add these classes to your project,

[image]

then update you Xaml to use them:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" listViewLayout:ListViewLayoutManager.Enabled="true" x:Name="Lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" listViewLayout:ProportionalColumn.Width="1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" listViewLayout:ProportionalColumn.Width="1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

the result in both solution is the same:

[image]